# How to show the collapsible menu in mobile view port in website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website, where It's okay for desktop. But I want to make may website mobile friendly also. So, What should I need to modified in the code section below?

I have used the meta tags for mobile viewports. But the following code can't show the collapsible menu in mobile devices. Please check the following code that I used and tried in `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Bob loves Alice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Assets/H_1.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="">
    <link href="Assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="---" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }

    .navbar-toggle {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="Assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#headerIncluder").load("header.html");
        $("#footerIncluder").load("footer.html");
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerIncluder"></div>
    ...
    ...
    <div id="headerIncluder"></div>
</body>
</html
```

And the `header.html` file is like below:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-id">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand active" href="http://abc.me/">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-id">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://abc.me/experience.html"><i class="fab fa-black-tie"></i> Experience</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://abc.me/researches.html"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Research</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://abc.me/publications.html">
                                <i class="fas fa-book"></i> Publications
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://blog.abc.me"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i><span class="hidden-md hidden-sm">Blog</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My expectation is to show the menu's under a hamburger menu when I visit from mobile devices. And keep it same for the desktop as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a couple items to deal with. First is that in your toggle button for the mobile nav, you're missing a few spans that will create the "layers" of your hamburger, so you're toggle button should look like:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-id">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Great, now we've got a hamburger but if you click it, nothing happens. You need to include the JS file that powers many of Bootstraps components. Just add the link for it AFTER your link to your jquery asset.

```
<script src="Assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And you should have a working mobile menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way to make good Desktop menu as well as mobile menu...

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}

function hide(obj) {
    obj.style.height = "0px";
    obj.style.visibility = "hidden";
    obj.style.opacity = "0";
}

function toggleNav(sub1, sub2) {
    var menu = document.getElementById("navBar");
    var subMenu1 = document.getElementById(sub1);
    var subMenu2 = document.getElementById(sub2);
    menu.style.transition = "0.5s";

    if (menu.style.height >= "320px") {
        hide(menu);
        hide(subMenu1);
        hide(subMenu2);
    }
    else {
        menu.style.opacity = "1";
        menu.style.height = "320px";
        menu.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function toogleSubMenus(main, sub) {
    var menu = document.getElementById(main);
    var subMenu = document.getElementById(sub);
    var mainMenu = document.getElementById("navBar").style;
    menu.style.transition = "0.5s";
    if (menu.style.height == "160px") {
        hide(menu);
        if (subMenu.style.height == "160px") {
            mainMenu.height = "480px";
        }
        else {
            mainMenu.height = "320px";
        }
    }
    else {
        menu.style.height = "160px";
        menu.style.opacity = "1";
        menu.style.visibility = "visible";
        if (subMenu.style.height == "160px") {
            mainMenu.height = "640px";
        }
        else {
            mainMenu.height = "480px";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-back-color: #F87C1D;
    --primary-back-color-hover: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    --bold-font: bold;
    --cursor-type: pointer;
    --side-padding: 0 10%;
    --side-padding-mobile: 0 5%;
}

/* Menu Bar Icon For Mobile View */

.barContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

#divNavMenu {
    background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
}

#divNavMobile {
    background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
    display: none;
}

    #divNavMenu nav, #divNavMobile nav {
        background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
    }

#divNavMenu nav {
    padding: var(--side-padding);
    height: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#divNavMobile nav {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    #divNavMenu nav ul, #divNavMobile nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style-image: none;
        line-height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
        padding: 0;
    }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li {
            float: left;
            width: 12.5%;
            position: relative;
        }

        #divNavMobile nav ul li {
            width: 100%;
        }

            #divNavMenu nav ul li a, #divNavMobile nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                cursor: var(--cursor-type);
                text-align: center;
                background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
                font-size: 14px;
                letter-spacing: 0.1px;
                font-weight: var(--bold-font);
            }

            #divNavMobile nav ul li a {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }

            #divNavMobile nav ul li ul li a {
                padding-left: 40px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            #divNavMenu nav ul li a:hover, #divNavMobile nav ul li a:hover {
                background-color: var(--primary-back-color-hover);
            }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li:hover > a {
            background-color: var(--primary-back-color-hover);
        }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }

            #divNavMenu nav ul li ul li a {
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 30px;
            }

        #divNavMobile nav ul li > ul {
            height: 0;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        #divNavMobile nav ul li ul li a {
            background-color: var(--primary-back-color-hover);
        }

            #divNavMobile nav ul li ul li a:hover {
                background-color: var(--primary-back-color);
            }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li ul li {
            width: 100%;
        }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li ul.subMenuCommunity {
            width: 390px;
        }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li ul.templeSubMenu {
            width: 220px;
        }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li ul li a {
            font-weight: var(--bold-font);
            line-height: 35px;
        }

@media (max-width: 1580px) {
    #divNavMenu nav ul li a {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1180px) {
    #divNavMenu nav ul li a {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    #divNavMenu nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #divNavMobile {
        display: block;
    }

    #divNavMenu nav {
        height: 0px;
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
    }

        #divNavMenu nav ul li {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
        }
}
```

```html
<div id="divNavMenu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.aspx">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="templeSubMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a>Menu 5</a>
                <ul class="subMenuCommunity">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Menu 6">TRUST MEMBERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="Menu 7">LIVE DARSHAN</a></li>
            <li><a href="Menu 8">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="divNavMobile">
    <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px; margin-left: 10px;" onclick="toggleNav('templeSubMenu','subMenuCommunity')">
        <div class="barContainer" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <div class="bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav id="navBar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.aspx">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="toogleSubMenus('templeSubMenu','subMenuCommunity')">Menu 2</a>
                <ul id="templeSubMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="toogleSubMenus('subMenuCommunity','templeSubMenu')">Menu 5</a>
                <ul id="subMenuCommunity">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```